# ASP Pages not rendering properly

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Good Morning,

I was having serious problems regarding this website.

What happens is everyytime I try to open a .shtml page in the site it always has an error "The Page Cannot Be Found" but this is highly unlikely since I already all have the resources in my local pc and already did a virtual directory for the entire site. Can you please tell me what's the problem? i've checked all the codes and they're constructed just fine.

Comment: I think we'll need some more information than this.  Can you open static .html pages?  Has it worked before and suddenly stopped working on your local pc?

Comment: Yes I can..sorry but that is all the information I can give. I'm just trying to understand classic ASP. The problem is even in our hosting site it still encounters the same error, the default page is made up of multiple .shtml files but they are still not rendered properly, I try to change their include from virtual into file but still its not working. thanks for the response

Comment: Version info please?  Note you can edit your question to refine its quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to view the page in Internet Explorer then I recommend turning off friendly HTTP error messages in the advanced settings. Disabling the setting may result in more verbose error messages, especially if it's an HTTP/500.

Comment: its an HTTP 404 error. Why is it raising a file not found error when all the resource file are in my local pc and all published according to the usual structure from the hosted website itslef. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an ASP problem. .shtml files are handled by the server-side include ISAPI application extension.

In Web service Extensions folder under the server icon in IIS manager, ensure that Server Sice Includes is set to "Allowed".